The following phrase App-DESKTOP-3A25GOE.config is added to the project file names in Visual Studio 2019 C# Windows Forms
For several days now I have not been able to execute my project on Visual Studio because it gives me a strange error and does not allow it to be built.
There is also a change to the file names (DESKTOP-3A25GOE) by adding the previous phrase before the dot.
This is for one project only and the rest of the projects are good.
I deleted the project and restored a previous copy that I had saved and it was completely fine and the same problem occurred.
I also deleted Visual Studio, installed it and the problem still exists.
I also formatted the device and downloaded and restored the system recovery and reinstalled Visual Studio and the same problem in addition to the project no longer being able to execute or build and also lost connection to the setting variables.
What is this problem please if anyone has experienced it?
Thank you

"strange error" - please share the exact error message

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\app.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt". Access to the path 'C:\Users\ali\repos\app\obj\Debug\app.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt' is denied. app
and

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The "GenerateBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\ali\repos\app\obj\Debug\app.exe.config' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileUtilities.OpenWrite(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateBindingRedirects.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() app

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The "ResolveComReference" task returned false but did not log an error. school

Unfortunately, I have started to suffer from deleting the executable file even though I downloaded Kaspersky Security and Avast Antivirus
And it can't access some libraries or build the project at all.
And I have become restricted and can't develop my project
Also, some libraries are still inaccessible and I cannot build the project at all.
I have become restricted and cannot develop my project and I do not know what the solution is!

Please add this important additional nformation to your question ([edit]) instead of posting as comment.
